# How to create check boxes, select multiple items and store them -- in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Working on a video-game review website for practice.

When creating a new video-game object, I have to assign platforms to them (xbox, playstation etc.)

my form is below and the Game model has many platforms, while the Platforms model belongs to game

Currently I use collection select. how do i turn this into checkboxes, and be able to select multiple platofrms with the checkboxes and save them?

thanks so much.

server log

```
Started PATCH "/games/6" for ::1 at 2015-07-08 05:07:59 -0400
Processing by GamesController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"√", "authenticity_token"=>"n9+Tnko0702pGPDbC3/rzdqGx92yR
ZZymKw3zd+dLwjl+zVqlrEa1yby1/xeXJVeXr+sht8XgXOD0ytCL+dnMw==", "game"=>{"title"=>
"Test", "release_date(1i)"=>"2015", "release_date(2i)"=>"7", "release_date(3i)"=
>"8", "genre_id"=>["1", ""], "platform_id"=>["1", ""]}, "commit"=>"Update Game",
 "id"=>"6"}
  User Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ?  ORDE
R BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  Game Load (1.0ms)  SELECT  "games".* FROM "games" WHERE "games"."id" = ? LIMIT
 1  [["id", 6]]
Unpermitted parameters: genre_id, platform_id
   (0.0ms)  begin transaction
   (0.0ms)  commit transaction
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/games/6
Completed 302 Found in 10ms (ActiveRecord: 1.0ms)


Started GET "/games/6" for ::1 at 2015-07-08 05:07:59 -0400
Processing by GamesController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"6"}
  User Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ?  ORDE
R BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  Game Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "games".* FROM "games" WHERE "games"."id" = ? LIMIT
 1  [["id", 6]]
   (0.0ms)  SELECT COUNT("previews"."vote") FROM "previews" WHERE "previews"."ga
me_id" = ?  [["game_id", 6]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT COUNT("previews"."vote") FROM "previews" WHERE "previews
"."game_id" = ?  [["game_id", 6]]
   (0.0ms)  SELECT COUNT("reviews"."vote") FROM "reviews" WHERE "reviews"."game_
id" = ?  [["game_id", 6]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT COUNT("reviews"."vote") FROM "reviews" WHERE "reviews"."
game_id" = ?  [["game_id", 6]]
  News Load (1.0ms)  SELECT  "news".* FROM "news" WHERE "news"."game_id" = ?  OR
DER BY "news"."id" DESC LIMIT 5  [["game_id", 6]]
  Rendered games/_review.html.erb (2.0ms)
  Review Load (1.0ms)  SELECT "reviews".* FROM "reviews" WHERE "reviews"."game_i
d" = ?  [["game_id", 6]]
   (0.0ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "reviews" WHERE "reviews"."game_id" = ?  [["gam
e_id", 6]]
  Review Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "reviews".* FROM "reviews" WHERE "reviews"."game_
id" = ?  ORDER BY "reviews"."id" DESC LIMIT 5  [["game_id", 6]]
  Rendered games/show.html.erb within layouts/application (16.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 162ms (Views: 157.1ms | ActiveRecord: 2.0ms)
```

server log 2 when using Emu's suggestion <-- still not saving, but unpermitted parameters error is gone.

```
Started PATCH "/games/6" for ::1 at 2015-07-08 05:56:55 -0400
Processing by GamesController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"√", "authenticity_token"=>"lzku1Wa89d6a2i2yArfyiyQwfhLcW
iigah0Pv6XpUAjtHYghujkARBUwCpVXlIwYoAkVSbEIP6FxYhMwVZMYMw==", "game"=>{"title"=>
"Test", "release_date(1i)"=>"2015", "release_date(2i)"=>"7", "release_date(3i)"=
>"8"}, "platform_ids"=>["4", "5"], "commit"=>"Update Game", "id"=>"6"}
  User Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ?  ORDE
R BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  Game Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "games".* FROM "games" WHERE "games"."id" = ? LIMIT
 1  [["id", 6]]
   (0.0ms)  begin transaction
   (0.0ms)  commit transaction
   (0.0ms)  begin transaction
   (0.0ms)  commit transaction
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/games/6
Completed 302 Found in 9ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)


Started GET "/games/6" for ::1 at 2015-07-08 05:56:55 -0400
Processing by GamesController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"6"}
  User Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ?  ORDE
R BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  Game Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "games".* FROM "games" WHERE "games"."id" = ? LIMIT
 1  [["id", 6]]
   (0.0ms)  SELECT COUNT("previews"."vote") FROM "previews" WHERE "previews"."ga
me_id" = ?  [["game_id", 6]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT COUNT("previews"."vote") FROM "previews" WHERE "previews
"."game_id" = ?  [["game_id", 6]]
   (0.0ms)  SELECT COUNT("reviews"."vote") FROM "reviews" WHERE "reviews"."game_
id" = ?  [["game_id", 6]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT COUNT("reviews"."vote") FROM "reviews" WHERE "reviews"."
game_id" = ?  [["game_id", 6]]
  News Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "news".* FROM "news" WHERE "news"."game_id" = ?  OR
DER BY "news"."id" DESC LIMIT 5  [["game_id", 6]]
  Rendered games/_review.html.erb (7.0ms)
  Review Load (0.0ms)  SELECT "reviews".* FROM "reviews" WHERE "reviews"."game_i
d" = ?  [["game_id", 6]]
   (0.0ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "reviews" WHERE "reviews"."game_id" = ?  [["gam
e_id", 6]]
  Review Load (1.0ms)  SELECT  "reviews".* FROM "reviews" WHERE "reviews"."game_
id" = ?  ORDER BY "reviews"."id" DESC LIMIT 5  [["game_id", 6]]
  Rendered games/show.html.erb within layouts/application (26.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 197ms (Views: 177.1ms | ActiveRecord: 3.0ms)
```

games table

```
create_table "games", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.string   "image"
    t.date     "release_date"
    t.datetime "created_at",   null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",   null: false
    t.integer  "platform_id"
    t.integer  "genre_id"
    t.integer  "review_id"
    t.integer  "steelbook_id"
  end
```

_game.html.erb <-- if I change the check boxes to use "genre_ids" and "platform_ids" i get a no method error at games#edit controller

```
<%= form_for @game do |g| %>

    <p><%= g.label :title %></p>
    <p><%= g.text_field :title %></p>

    <p><%= g.label :release_date %></p>
    <p><%= g.date_select :release_date %></p>

    <p><%= g.label :genre_id %></p>
    <p><%= g.collection_check_boxes :genre_id, @genres, :id, :category %></p>

    <p><%= g.label "Platform(s)" %></p>

    <p><%= g.collection_check_boxes :platform_id, @platforms, :id, :system %></p>

    <p><%= g.label :image %></p>
    <p><%= g.file_field :image %></p>

<hr>
    <p><%= g.submit %></p>

<% end %>
```

game controller

```
class GamesController < ApplicationController

    before_action :authenticate_user!
    before_action :set_game, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]


    def index
        @games = Game.all
    end

    def show
        @reviews = Review.where(game_id: @game.id)
        @previews = Preview.where(game_id: @game.id)
        @news = News.where(game_id: @game.id)
    end

    def create
        @game = Game.new(game_params)
        @game.save
        redirect_to @game
    end

    def new
        @game = Game.new
        set_platforms
        set_genres
    end

    def edit
        set_platforms
        set_genres
    end

    def update
        @game.update(game_params)
        redirect_to @game
    end

    def destroy
        @game.destroy
        redirect_to root_path
    end

private

    def game_params
       params.require(:game).permit(:title, :image, :release_date, :genre_ids => [], :platform_ids => [])
    end

    def set_game
        @game = Game.find(params[:id])
    end

    def set_platforms
        @platforms = Platform.order(:system)
    end

    def set_genres
        @genres = Genre.order(:category)
    end

end
```

routes

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  devise_for :users

  root "games#index"

  resources :games do
    resources :news
    resources :reviews, except: [:show]
    resources :previews, except: [:show]
  end

  resources :platforms
  resources :genres

end
```

platforms model

```
class Platform < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :game
end
```

game model

```
class Game < ActiveRecord::Base

    has_many :platforms
    has_many :preview, through: :users
    has_many :reviews, through: :users
    has_many :news

    has_one :genre  

end
```

Comment: Can you post your model associations please?

Answer (score 0):

For each platform create a new checkbox using the loop below:

```
<% @platforms.each do |platform| %>
  <%= check_box_tag "platform_ids[]", platform.id %>
  <%= platform.name %> // I assume that your platform has a name which can be used as a label
<% end %>
```

In the **controller** you can access the values of the checkboxes using `params[:platform_ids]`

Just change the **game_params** method in the controller with the following code:

```
def game_params
    params.require(:game).permit(:title, :image, :release_date, :genre_id, :platform_ids => [])
end
```

**or**
you can see a [railscasts](http://railscasts.com/episodes/52-update-through-checkboxes) video.

Comment: hey thank you. i do see 4 boxes created, but the values or names aren't showing up. i edited my post. can you provide walkthrough on how to set it up in the controller? currently i have `@platforms = Platform.order(:system)` which helps with the collection select...

Comment: @giantqtipz, edited my answer with the checkbox label and controller method change. Hope you would find that helpful!

Comment: Hi :) i experimented with `your check_box_tag`, and when i look at the server log, it's being committed. when i use `collection_check_boxes`, i get unpermitted parameters. the issue is, its still not saving. when I do `Game.all`, the `platform_id` value is still nil

Comment: @giantqtipz, In your single `game` you're having a integer column `platform_id` to save the platform, but from your `_game.html.erb` you will get an array of `platforms`. So, now tell me how can a array save to a integer column?

Comment: @giantqtipz, Your association is wrong. It would be a `many-to-many` relation between `Game` and `Platform`. Please read the rails guides first. :D

Comment: thank you! im at work right now but on the train ride here,  i googled and learned about serialize! i cant wait to go home and serialize the hell out of `:platform_ids` :) thanks everyone for your patience with me. really glad i learned something new today.

Comment: @giantqtipz, then you should close the question by accepting an answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**collection_check_boxes**](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/collection_check_boxes).

```
<p><%= g.collection_check_boxes :platform_ids, @platforms, :id, :system %></p>
```

And change `game_params` to the following.

```
def game_params
   params.require(:game).permit(:title, :image, :release_date, :genre_id, :platform_ids => [])
end
```

Didn't tested it. I guess you require a little tweak in the code.

Comment: Hi Pavan, many thanks for the input. I'm still having problems however.this is what I'm getting when i inspect a check box `<input type="checkbox" value="1" name="game[platform_id][]" id="game_platform_id_1">` is that correct? the values are still not saving when i select 1 or multiple check boxes. do you think its my `set_platforms` action in the controller? also in the params, i tried `:platform_id => [:system]` as well but with no luck.

Comment: @giantqtipz Did you updated with my changes and checked?

Comment: yes, i took both lines you suggested. i googled for permitting strong parameters and the suggestions online are also similar to `:platform_ids => []` but for some reason still not working... i added my routes and models too

Comment: @giantqtipz Can you post the server log generated while submitting the form?

Comment: i added the log.i forgot about checking the log! it says unpermitted parameters! why is that the case? it saves fine when i use collection select. and for genre_id, i added `=> []` as well in the `game_params`. i want to use checkbox for it too

Comment: @giantqtipz Do you have those attributes in your games table?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82680/discussion-between-pavan-and-giantqtipz).

Comment: @giantqtipz Use `:genre_ids` and `:platform_ids` instead

Comment: @giantqtipz And also make the changes in `game_params` method too :)

Comment: hi pavan, do you mean use `:genre_ids` and `:platform_ids` in the `game_params?` because it still won't work. and if make them plural adding "s" to both ids in the form, i get a no method error in `games#edit`

Comment: just want to update. when i use Emu's suggestions below -- i dont get the unpermitted parameters error in the server log. but it's still not saving -- when i type `Game.all` the value for `platform_id` is still nil

Comment: Currently there is no `platform_id` input field in your `_game.html.erb`. Now it is `platform_ids[]`. So, how you supposed to save an array to any integer column? Read my comment under my answer.